# Assign value to hidden textarea onSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two `textarea` fields, the first one is hidden and the second is visible, My question is how can I assign the content of the visible one to the hidden when the submit button is clicked?

Any suggestion? don't matter (**Javascript** or **Jquery**) the both will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jquery you can set the value of the hidden field upon the submit event being fired.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('#txt1_hidden').val($('#txt1_visible').val());
})
```

If you want you can bind the items together so that anytime the visible textarea changes it will automatically update the hidden item.

```
$('#txt1_visible').on('input propertychange paste change', function(e) {
  $('#txt1_hidden').val(this.value);
});
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/ap3cqhzr/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the val() method :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style id="jsbin-css">
textarea[name=hidden]{
  display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="myForm">
  <textarea name="visible" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <textarea name="hidden" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
$("#myForm").on("submit",function(e){
  //Prevent the submission of the form
  //(if you want to submit it, you need to submit it after the duplication of your text are
  e.preventDefault();
 $("textarea[name=hidden]").val($("textarea[name=visible]").val());
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this way, you can do the duplication on any event! For instance :

```
$("textarea[name=visible]").on("change",function(){
  ...
});
```

example : http://jsbin.com/gumibif/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript solution**

You could use `onsubmit` event and assign the content to the hidden field inside it :

```
document.form[0].onsubmit=function()
{
    //Get visible input value
    var visible_input_value = document.getElementById('visible-input').value;

    //Assign the previous value to the hidden input
    document.getElementById('hidden-input').value = visible_input_value;
};
```

**JQuery solution**

Same thing in jquery using `submit` event and `val()` function to get/set the value to the field :

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function() {
    //Get visible input value
    var visible_input_value = $('#visible-input').val();

    //Assign the previous value to the hidden input
    $('#hidden-input').val( visible_input_value );
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal:

```js
$(function () {
  var content = "This is a sample text!"
  $('<textarea id="myFirsttxtarea">' + content + '</textarea><br/>').insertBefore('#myForm input[type="submit"]');
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    
    // on submit do: now nothing
    e.preventDefault();
    
    // clone the element and hide
    $('#myFirsttxtarea').clone().attr('id', 'mySecondtxtarea').hide().insertBefore('#myForm input[type="submit"]');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<form id="myForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your code seems to get the job done. Although havn't tried it but I never wanted to introduce a variable i.e **content**

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Simple and straight:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  $('textarea#txt1_hidden').val($('textarea#txt1').val());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ap3cqhzr/1/